# Difference between two functions in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I was learning few functions and came across these:

```
df.groupby("date").agg("user_id": pd.Series.nunique)
```

and

```
df.groupby("date")["user_id"].transform('count')
```

I would like to know and learn on the differences between the above two statements.

Thanks!

Comment: compare results which you get and you will see difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date':['2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', 
                '2019-01-02', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-02'],
         'user_id':[np.nan,4,4,5,5,4],

})

print (df)
         date  user_id
0  2019-01-01      NaN
1  2019-01-01      4.0
2  2019-01-01      4.0
3  2019-01-02      5.0
4  2019-01-02      5.0
5  2019-01-02      4.0
```

First difference is here is used aggregation, reduce rows by some aggregate function. Here is used [`Series.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) for count number of unique values, missing valeus are omitted, so for first group get `1`, for second `2`:

```
print (df.groupby("date").agg({"user_id": pd.Series.nunique}))
            user_id
date               
2019-01-01      1.0
2019-01-02      2.0
```

If is used [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) also is count missinf values like unique value:

```
print (df.groupby("date")["user_id"].nunique())
date
2019-01-01    2
2019-01-02    2
Name: user_id, dtype: int64
```

Looks like bug, because:

```
print (df.groupby("date")["user_id"].nunique(dropna=True))
date
2019-01-01    2
2019-01-02    2
Name: user_id, dtype: int64

print (df.groupby("date")["user_id"].nunique(dropna=False))
date
2019-01-01    2
2019-01-02    2
Name: user_id, dtype: int64
```

If use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) then is applied aggregate function, but rows are not reduced, but same values are repeated for same group, so get new `Series` with same length like original.

Also [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) id used for count number of values with exclude missing values, so for first group get `2` and for second, because no missing values, `3`:

```
print (df.groupby("date")["user_id"].transform('count'))
0    2
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    3
Name: user_id, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Great explanation @jezrael, how could I use `distinct count` with `print (df.groupby("date")["user_id"].transform('count'))`

Comment: @omdurg - Do you think `print (df.groupby("date")["user_id"].transform('nunique'))` ?